# Deprecation warning from shell module

Tags: ansible, ansible-bug

I'm learning Ansible and I get the following warning from shell module and I can't fix it (I did try to declare a type bool as suggested by the warning)
Could you help me to understand this warning message?

The warning message:

```
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: evaluating {'stderr_lines': [], u'changed': True, u'end': u'2019-12-06 03:00:22.120779', 'failed': False, u'stdout': u' xxxx.fr', u'cmd': u"pcs config | grep 'Pacemaker 
Nodes:' -A1 | tail -1 | grep xxxx.fr", u'rc': 0, u'start': u'2019-12-06 03:00:21.786650', u'stderr': u'', u'delta': u'0:00:00.334129', 'stdout_lines': [u' xxxx.fr'], 
'failed_when_result': False} as a bare variable, this behaviour will go away and you might need to add |bool to the expression in the future. Also see CONDITIONAL_BARE_VARS configuration toggle.. This feature will be removed in version 
2.12. Deprecation warnings can be disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.
```

This is my task:

```
tasks:
   #Identification du role dans un cluster Pacemaker
   - name: "Set cluster role"
    block:
      #Identification du serveur comme slave pacemaker cluster
       - name: "Is a cluster node?"
         shell: "pcs config | grep 'Pacemaker Nodes:' -A1 | tail -1 | grep {{ inventory_hostname }}"
         register: cluster
         changed_when: cluster.rc == 0
         failed_when: false
```

Comment: Hi Pierre, welcome to SO. Are you certain you posted the code you are actually running, because there doesn't appear to be any [bare variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/porting_guides/porting_guide_2.8.html#bare-variables-in-conditionals) in use in your provided snippet; also, what version of ansible are you currently using?

Comment: It's a bug. See [spurious CONDITIONAL_BARE_VARS warnings #53428](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/53428) and [improve conditional warnings #57190](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/57190). Fixed in [Ansible 2.9](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.9/changelogs/CHANGELOG-v2.9.rst#id22).

Comment: @VladimirBotka thanks a lot for your answer,  I'm relieved to find out that is a bug...